# histogram-like plot with different colors in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a vector `data` in a histogram-like style. This is always kind of easy, because `plot(data, type="h")` does exactly what I want. However, there is a problem with the color. My vector `data` looks like this:

```
 data = c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3, ... )
```

What I want to see, is that each `1` is plotted in one color, each `2` in a different color and each `3` likewise. I tried to achieve that with

```
 plot(data, type="h", col=c("red","blue","green")
```

but it failed with R looping over the color vector, so that the first bar was red, the second blue, the third green, the fourth red again and so on.

I am very interessted in general solution, because my `data` vectors do not always consist of the numbers `1`, `2` and `3`. There are many cases in which the vector holds the numbers from 1 to 6.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to create a vector of colors of the same length, like this:

```
data = c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3)
colors = c("red","blue","green")
plot(data, type="h", col=colors[data])
```

This works because `colors[data]` looks like:

```
print(colors[data])
#  [1] "red"   "blue"  "blue"  "green" "red"   "red"   "blue"  "green" "red"  
# [10] "blue"  "blue"  "green"
```

Comment: how can i apply this to a range of data? For example, i would like to have anything that falls between -100 and 100 as red and everything else blue?

Comment: @user1007742: Use `cut` to divide it: i.e. `mydatacut = cut(x, c(-Inf, -100, 100, Inf))`. This will create a factor with three levels Then you can do `colors[as.numeric(mydatacut)]` where factor is, in your example, `c("blue", "red", "blue")`

Answer (score 6):

try this for general method:

```
data = c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,3)
colors = rainbow(length(unique(data)))
plot(data, type="h", col=colors[data])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 colors = rainbow(length(unique(data)));
 hist(data, col=colors[data])
```

Using mr. lapalme's data (above)